# Monitor all activities over the Zabbix Dashboard

Tags: zabbix

I want to Monitor the Zabbix Dashboard Itself. As i am using a zabbix setup with 1000 hosts many triggers, templates. So now i want to monitor that if a trigger or template is disabled , enabled , if any new trigger is created and vice versa for any hosts then which user has made these changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can see, and filter, all events through the [Audit Report](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/reports/audit). There is not (yet) an API call to read the Audit logs.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about details but I remember my colleague used to login to the Zabbix's MySQL database and select desired things. You could try selecting "disabled" from the particular table but the more detailed research you'd need to do on your own.